# extract data from website using Bautifulsoup in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract data from website http://www.bcsfootball.org

In this website I'm looking to extract Welcome block with all text in it.

Here is my code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bcsfootball.org').read())

for row in soup('table',{'class':mod-container mod-no-footer mod-open'})[0].tbody('tr'):
tds = row('td')
print (tds[0].string, tds[1].string)
```

error

```
    for row in soup('table',{'class':mod-container mod-no-footer mod-open'})[0].tbody('tr'):
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please anyone can help me where am doing wrong ? I'm new to python

Please also help me to understand [0].tbody('tr'): in code. What its doing exactly ?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `'` before `mod-container`. Here is the corrected version: `... 'class': 'mod-container mod-no-footer mod-open' ...`

Comment: you're missing a `'` after the first `:`

Comment: thanks to notify me on my silly mistake. Please check my little updated question....

Comment: Your code will not work for the mentioned web page. because "Welcome" block has `div` tag but you are using `table` tag which is not correct

Comment: @Prabhakar, So what is the correct way to do it. I want to extract welcome block with content in that block. And getting error after running this code like "list index out of range" Can you help to get through it ?

Answer (score 0):

this code should work, you were missing an apostrophe.

Code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bcsfootball.org').read())

for row in soup('table',{'class':'mod-container mod-no-footer mod-open'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
print (tds[0].string, tds[1].string)
```

Comment: Could you please help me to understand [0].tbody('tr') in code ?

Comment: I don't know, I just copied it from your code @kate